# How to debug a standalone GAS script?

Tags: debugging, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

I'm grappling with the issue of how to debug a standalone GAS script (in this case, one to be used as a Sheets add-on).

There is no debug configuration. I can use parameter-less entry points creating mock objects to debug functions app-agnostically, but this is all published in the release package. Also, if these functions are not private (i.e. not ending in `_`), they're exposed to a Sheets add-on; however, if they are private, they can't be selected as a debug entry point!

[The official doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints) doesn't acknowledge this problem. [This wonderful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089041/how-can-i-test-a-trigger-function-in-gas/16089067#16089067) does not apply, since you can't access `SpreadsheetApp` while debugging a *standalone* script rather than a bound script (and it doesn't fix the above problem of the function being exposed as a custom function to Sheets).

In short, **how can I set up an environment that lets me toggle a breakpoint, press "Debug", and step through code as needed?**

Comment: You can certainly access `SpreadsheetApp` from a standalone script. You can't use `getActive____()` methods, but you can absolutely open using `fileId`s / URLs.

Comment: It sounds like it might be time for you to learn about developer tools.

Comment: @Cooper Could you expand?

Comment: The developer tools in your browser.  The console section.  The source section.  Look at the tools in your browser.